# Android Fragment lifecycle makes app crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

When a `Fragment` displaying info for  a custom `Session` object is created, I need to load the UI with the properties for the selected `Session`.

This works fine when the `Fragment` is created for the first time
I wrote the code for the set up  in `onStart`, because layout isn't inflated until `onCreateView`, which is called before `onStart`. (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

The problem is : Whenever the phone is rotated, the app crashes, apparently because `onStart` gets called,

I tried using `onActivityCreated` and `onResume` instead but neither worked, and this are the only three functions called automatically after `onCreateView`

What can I do without disabling rotation ?

There is a good diagram of the fragment lifecycle here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

```
05-12 01:03:12.968  21599-21599/com.example.kn.ib W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418f3da0)
    05-12 01:03:12.968  21599-21599/com.example.kn.ib E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.kn.ib, PID: 21599
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kn.ib/com.example.kn.ib.IBCentralActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3924)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:161)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.example
                at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1708)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1853)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5429)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3924)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:161)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Fragment onStart (line 117 is                 `"ID: "+ session._id + "\n" +`)

```
   @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        sessionID = activityCallback.getSelectedSessionID();
        db = activityCallback.getSessionDatabase();

        session = db.getSession(sessionID);

        TextView textViewForTesting = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.test);
        String testText = "\n" +
                "ID: "+ session._id + "\n" +
                "LAP COUNT: "+ session._lapCount + "\n" +
                "DATE: "+ session._date + "\n" +
                "CALORIES: "+ session._calories + "\n" +
                "ISOPEN: "+ session._isOpen + "\n" +
                "LASTMOD: "+ session._lastMod;

        textViewForTesting.setText(testText);

        Button saveButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.SessionInfo_SaveButton);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        isOpenTextField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.ISOPEN);
        poolSizeTextField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.POOLSIZE);
        commentTextField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.COMMENT);
        metricTextField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.METRIC);


   
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                dateField.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },sessionYear, sessionMonth, sessionDay);

        timeField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.sessionTimeField);
        //TODO: set user preferences for time format HH or KK
        timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);

        timeField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        timeField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
        timeField.setText(sessionHour + ":" + sessionMinute);

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,  int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                Calendar newTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hr = newTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int mn = newTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                /*TODO: set user preferences for time format HH or KK */
                dateField.setText(hr+":"+mn);
            }

        },sessionHour, sessionMinute, true/*TODO: set user preferences for time format HH or KK */);
        isOpenTextField.setText(session._isOpen+"");
        metricTextField.setText(session._metric);
        commentTextField.setText(session._comment);
        poolSizeTextField.setText("" + session._poolSize);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the layout code? How are you retaining the session object?

Comment: also the stacktrace is useful

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "crash without stacktrace"

Comment: Ok I've added the stack trace, Doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: It's going to be impossible to help without code.  From the stack trace, this current crash is happening due to an NPE at `IBSessionInfoFragment.java:1171`.

Comment: The calls made to the fragment's overriden methods (onStart, ect.) arnt the same when you first create it and when the app gets rotated.

Comment: @BartdeRuijter what method should I override then ?

Comment: @aorlando, I know the session that's created after the rotation is null, which is why the app is crashing. What I'm trying to do is find a method that isn't called when the phone is rotated

Comment: on rotation your activity is re-created, so fragments are re-created all lifecycle are called. but, something seems to buffle me your stacktrace points to `onActivityCreated()` method line 117 and you are saying its in `onStart()` ? why?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Depends, what is "activityCallback"? Is it a variable you define somewhere? And can you verify that .getSelectedSessionId() returns your desired value? (e.g. Log.e("MyId", activityCallback.getSelectedSessionId()); Perhaps you got some code where you set the activityCallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity and fragment lifecycle are not trivial on android.
Please remember activity and fragment will be destroyed and recreated on device rotation so,if you need a method not called again you can use onCreate method  of the fragment and put setRetainInstanceState(true) inside the same method. In this way the fragment will retained and not destroyed on device orientation changes.
 Also you must define the fragment in your xml layout and you must assign an id, if your layout is added programmaticcally or does not have a UI  you can use the FragmentManager and a tag to add and retrieve the fragment.

You can check on android [handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) guide

Comment: Yes, the problem with onCreate is that it doesn't find my UI elements, the layout isn't loaded until `onCreateView` is called